# programmatically, call forwarding in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

how can we programmatically implement, call forwarding?
I have done some google search, but have not found any good solution.
For reference, i have gone through this web page

[CLick here](http://www.fryfilm.com/infopages/iphonecodes.htm)

Suggestions are always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see this thread is a little old, but I’ll give you my 2 cents worth which might help you out when it comes to call forwarding.

I’ve recently released an app Ridlee+ on the Kuwait app store it has a call forwarding feature implemented and I faced the same issues you all are having.

So basically, the method described here using  -[NSApplication openURL:]  us correct, The problem is that apple will not allow you to pass  * or # to the number programmatically, and as far as I know you need those in the dial number to interact with the call forwarding option on the telecom side.   So the answer is “It’s not doable “
What I did is suggest to the telecom to create a link between the two, so I would pass call forwarding requests through TCP/IP or network connectivity to a webservice, and that system will take care of the internal config on the telecom side.

You will face issues requesting such a thing from the telecom since you get into User verification arguments, but if you implement your app correctly they would consider it.   The way I did it, is have the User verified using a small reg process where the user will send a free SMS to the telecom, who will pass back to the webserver a verification code assigned to the user,  the user will then enter this code in the app, which in turn verifies it with the web server, this 3 way handshake allows you to verify the user is the phone number owner. In turn allowing him to control his forwarding through the web service.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the call forwarding character to the `-[NSApplication openURL:]` method?

Comment: Hey PeyloW, -[NSApplication openURL:] is used to open webpage right?? i want to implement call forwarding

Comment: Try doing a `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0704106983"]];`. Replace with your own phone number, it works and will place a call. Look at the documentation for the method for more supported URL schemas *(for example sending text messages)*.

Comment: Hey peyloW, i tried ur approch, but i m not able to get call forwarding working properly. Plz suggest.

Comment: @shishir.bobby - I can not say more than is available in Apple's documentation, and refer to what I have tried myself. If that does not help you, then you need to contact Apple developer support.

Comment: Thanks, but when u tried this for call forwarding does it worked? i mean if u use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0704106983"]]; that will go for calling, but for call forwarding, we need add, GSM code right? like            to activate we use Activate: *21*[dest]#.

Comment: For the call forwarding how you write [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0704106983"]]; method.